# Group Array into a more complex Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

1. I create an array of Objects from a database query and call the
   array jobListRecords. There are multiple records in the array created that have the same "customerID" and "name".
2. I would like to create a new array that has one record for each customer with a new field , "jobArray", that contains another array of all of that customers services. (see sortCustomer array down below)

An example of the initial array:

```
jobListRecords = [
    { 
    "customerID" : "1",
    "name" : "Larry Bird",
    "serviceID" : "101",
    "serviceName" : "Dog Walking"
    },
    {
    "customerID" : "2",
    "name" : "Andrew Luck",
    "serviceID" : "202",
    "serviceName" : "Baby Sitting"
    },
    {
    "customerID" : "2",
    "name" : "Andrew Luck",
    "serviceID" : "101",
    "serviceName" : "Dog Walking"
    }
]
```

Desired Result

sortCustomer Example:

```
sortCustomer = [
   {
   "customerID" : "1",
   "name" : " Larry Bird",
   "jobArray" : [
           {
           "serviceID" : "101",
           "serviceName" : "Dog Walking"
           }
        ]
    },
    {
    "customerID" : "2",
    "name" : "Andrew Luck",
    "jobArray" : [
            {
            "serviceID" : "202",
            "serviceName" : "Baby Sitting"
            },
            {
           "serviceID" : "101",
            "serviceName" : "Dog Walking"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is their a simple or efficient way of solving this without having to iterate through all the data 3+ times. Thank You for your time, below is one of the several things I tried.

I tried solving this using one example I found but it grouped all the serviceIDs together which is not what I need.

Example that DID NOT work that I tried.

```
jobListGrouped = _
    .chain(jobListRecords)
    .groupBy('customerID')
    .map(function(value, key) {
        return {
            CustomerID: key,
            services: _.pluck(value, 'serviceID')
        }
    })
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `pluck`ing only the `serviceIDs` into that array. Instead, you would need to do something like

```
.map(function(values, key) {
    return {
        customerID: key,
        name: values[0].name.
        services: _.map(values, _.partial(_.pick, _, 'serviceID', 'serviceName'))
    }
})
```

or even more explicit

```
.map(function(values, key) {
    return _.extend(_.omit(values[0], 'serviceID', 'serviceName'), {
        services: _.map(values, _.partial(_.pick, _, 'serviceID', 'serviceName'))
    }
})
```

(where that `partial` call is the same as `function(value) { return _.pick(value, 'serviceID', 'serviceName'); }`)

Comment: When I try your first example it is resulting in what appears to be the structure I am looking for but the service field is an array of  empty objects. The correct number of objects but they are empty. I will try the more explicit option as well.

Comment: I used the first solution but replaced the _.partial with the function(value) { return _.pick (value, 'serviceID', 'serviceName');} and this worked. Do you know why this would happen? I marked you correct.

Comment: Possibly your underscore version does not support `_` as an omitted argument for `partial`?